# HTML5 drop event doesn't work unless dragover is handled

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, dom-events

I am listening to the `drop` event and doing `e.preventDefault()` But its trying to open the dropped file. It was working fine till yesterday. But just today It broke for some unknown reason. I made a [`JsFiddle#bwquR/10`](http://jsfiddle.net/bwquR/10/) to reflect the Same.

### Edit:

It looks like if you don't take the `dragover` event `drop` cannot be handled. even in the      the fiddle If you comment the `dragover` It will not work.
In the actual work I missed the spelling of `dragover` But its still a question `drop` will not work without `dragover`

The fiddle was actually working but s the body was so small (only text `DROP` there). It was taking `drop` event only on that small area where `DROP` text lies not on the entire body. So I thought It was not working. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Just had this issue and your question helped me resolve it. I returned false in the dragover event and drop started working.. THANKS!!!

Comment: Sometimes it helps to define a bit of css ``body { width:300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid #f1f1f1; }`` just so you can actually see the size of your drop area. Nice example btw.

Answer (score 52):

I guess it is because that without dragOver event handler, default event handler of dragOver event is used, thus, no drop event is triggered after that. There is a need with `e.preventDefault` for dragOver event before drop event.

Comment: Oh man, this is such a bad system design. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @cronoklee 4 years later and I still say the same. Bad tricky design

Answer (score 9):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Drag_operations

If you want to allow a drop, you must prevent the default handling by cancelling the event. You can do this either by returning false from an attribute-defined event listener, or by calling the event's event.preventDefault method. The latter may be more feasible in a function defined in a separate script.

```
<div ondragover="return false">
<div ondragover="event.preventDefault()">
```

Calling the preventDefault method during both a dragenter and dragover event will indicate that a drop is allowed at that location. However, you will commonly wish to call the preventDefault method only in certain situations, for example, only if a link is being dragged. To do this, call a function which checks a condition and only cancels the event when the condition is met. If the condition is not met, don't cancel the event, and a drop will not occur there if the user releases the mouse button.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dragover

```
  /* events fired on the drop targets */
  document.addEventListener("dragover", function( event ) {
      // prevent default to allow drop
      event.preventDefault();
  }, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. There is one more paragraph that you did not quote, but IMHO is very important to explain the WHY: "A listener for the dragenter and dragover events are used to indicate valid drop targets, that is, places where dragged items may be dropped. **Most areas of a web page or application are not valid places to drop data. Thus, the default handling of these events is not to allow a drop.**"

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly but if you want to read dropped files you need to handle dragover event and put there at least this line of code:

```
evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
```

otherwise dropEffect is null by default and you won't get any data.

Comment: That is the culprit that prevented me from getting into ``drop()`` event. Except I had to use ``evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy";`` to prevent ``Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'dropEffect' of undefined`` while I hold files over the drop area.

Comment: @iiminov You had to do that because you're using jQuery. jQuery creates a custom event object and keep the original one under the `originalEvent` property.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me. Are you loading this as an HTTP or a FILE URL? I believe it needs to be an HTTP URL with Chrome.

Comment: as HTTP localhost. It was working Fine till yesterday. I can't understand what has happened.

Comment: The JsFiddle works just as expected for me in Chrome. I get the DragOver message as soon as file is over the DROP. And when I comment that alert out I can drop it and get the Dropped message.

Comment: It was working for me too. But in the area where `DROP` is written. not in the entire body. So I thought It was not working. sorry. However I've edited My question. Sorry