# Unable to detect the drop event in chrome extension when dropped a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, drag-and-drop

I am building a chrome extension which will let the user to drag and drop files and save the same to the server. From the extension I have injected a `div` element in the page when I drop an image file the browser is displaying the image on the entire page. The `drop` event is not getting detected in the extension, but if I have a input element with the type file and if I drop the file on that element then the `change` event is getting detected.

Not sure how to detect the `drop` event from the extension. Any help is appreciated.

**contentScript.js file**

```
//building the Dropzone Div
var dropdiv = $("<div>", {
  id    :"sforce-dz-dropZone",
  class : "sforce-dz-dropZonebg"
}).text('Add you\'re files here');

//injecting the drop div in the page
$("input[name=attachFile]").after(dropdiv);

//adding 'drop' event listener to the div.
//This is not getting logged at all.
$("#sforce-dz-dropZone").on('drop', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
  // process all File objects
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
    console.log('the file name is '+ f.name);
  }

});

//Adding another event. click, just to see if the events are getting triggered.
//When clicked on the div the console is logging the below string.
$("#sforce-dz-dropZone").on('click',function(){
  console.log('clicked');
});
```

**Manifest File**

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "text",
  "author": "someone",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches" : ["https://*.mysite.com/*"],
       "js"     : ["jquery.js","contentScript.js"],
       "css"    : ["sforce-dz.css"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
     "cookies",
     "unlimitedStorage"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Where is this code in your extension, and show us the manifest and/or how you inject this code.

Comment: I edited my comment. THe div is getting injected just fine. All I am not able to do is not able to detect the `drop` event in the javascript contentScript

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a really confusing part of handling drag and drop. You'd expect to just listen for the `drop` event as you do with `click submit mouseOver` etc. But it won't work unless it also has a `dragOver` event.

"without the dragOver event handler, the default event handler from dragOver event is used, thus, no drop event is triggered." [Answer Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414154/html5-drop-event-doesnt-work-unless-dragover-is-handled)

#### Simplest working example

```
/* events fired on the drop targets */
document.addEventListener("dragover", function( event ) {
  // prevent default to allow drop
  event.preventDefault();
});

document.addEventListener("drop", function( event ) {
  // prevent default action (open as link for some elements)
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('dropped');
});
```

#### Working example from HTML5Rocks

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation();
  evt.preventDefault();

  var files = evt.dataTransfer.files; // FileList object.

  // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
    output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
                f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
                '</li>');
  }
  document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
}

function handleDragOver(evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation();
  evt.preventDefault();
  evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'; // Explicitly show this is a copy.
}

// Setup the dnd listeners.
var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop_zone');
dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
dropZone.addEventListener('drop', handleFileSelect, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dropdiv.on('dragover', function (e) {
    return false;
});
```

When mouse is above our drop-area, you must return 'false'.

This way realized filtering of sources.

I recommend you to read a book written by David Flanagan: "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide"