# drop event dataTransfer.getData() returns "" on Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to find out why a drag & drop feature on our AngularJS app doesn't work with Firefox but it does on Chrome, and after looking into it for a while, I don't know what's wrong because apparently it should work.

This is the drop event listener:

```
    document.addEventListener("drop", function(event) {
        console.log(event);
        event.preventDefault();
        vm.msg = {};
        vm.msg.appName = event.dataTransfer.getData("appName");
        vm.msg.code = event.dataTransfer.getData("code");
        vm.msg.url = event.dataTransfer.getData("url");
        vm.msg.structure = event.dataTransfer.getData("structure");
        console.log(vm.msg);
        dropping(vm.msg);
    });
```

On Chrome this works perfectly. On firefox however, it "works". Event is captured, code executed, even.dataTransfer has all intended types (appName, code, url, structure and some more), 'kind' is properly defined for all of them (string)... all I got too see with Firebug is fine.

But `event.dataTransfer.getData("appName")` (or whatever type) returns empty string `""` and no errors nor warnings are thrown. I don't know whats wrong or what I'm missing.

---

*//EDIT 2017-05-26: More information*

Because the template where drop is being made is from a directive shared by other applications I have to apply changes from my controller:

```
    angular.element('#dropSide').bind('dragover', function(){

        if (vm.itemsDragging.length === 0){
          vm.itemsDragging = angular.element(' .tree-row.tree-row-type,.tree-row.tree-row-type-level');
        }

        angular.forEach(vm.itemsDragging,function(obj){
            $(obj).unbind('dragover');
            $(obj).bind('dragover', function(event){
              vm.node = $(event.currentTarget.children[0].children[0]);
              event.preventDefault();
              $(obj).addClass('dragging');
            });
            $(obj).unbind('dragleave');
            $(obj).bind('dragleave', function(event){
              event.preventDefault();
              $(obj).removeClass('dragging');
            });
            $(obj).unbind('drop');
            $(obj).bind('drop', function(event){
              event.preventDefault();
              $(obj).removeClass('dragging');
            });
        });
    });
```

This works fine on Firefox.

Source of the drag is an angular app on another domain which we access like this:

```
  <div class="container-vide">
    <object ng-cloak 
            id="dragsource"
            data="https://{{vm.dragsourceurl}}" 
            type="text/html">      
    </object>
  </div>
```

A customized ng-draggable directive is used on that other domain to populate the data. Also working fine on Firefox.

```
        element.bind("dragstart", function (eventObject) {
            console.log('dragstart');
            for (var attr in attributes) {
                if (attr.substring(0, 4) === 'drag') {
                    eventObject.dataTransfer.setData(attr.substring(4).toLowerCase(), attributes[attr]);
                }
            }
```

Template

```
<span ng-draggable 
            drag-appname="App Name" 
            drag-structure="Default Structure"
            drag-code="1" 
            drag-url="mockurl.com"
            class="draggable">
</span>
```

---

//EDIT: again, more info

I been debugging a lot today to play the "find differences" game and so far I've only found one.

For both Chrome/Firefox the managing of the events is exactly the same, but I discovered (based on an answer here: [HTML5 drop event doesn't work unless dragover is handled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414154/html5-drop-event-doesnt-work-unless-dragover-is-handled)) that if I change the dropEffect on **dragover** event from 'none' to 'copy'

```
event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
```

In Chrome, on drop event I get 'none' as dropEffect (so changes made no effect to this event), but on Firefox drop event has 'copy' as dropEffect.

That's the only difference I found so far until now.

Therebefore, my now theory is that I'm entering the drop listener with the dragover event on Firefox, which of course doesn't allow access to Data yet. Still, I don't know why is that hapenning nor how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

See below code I have checked it is working in firefox.

```js
function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("appName", "Default App");
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("code", "Code - 1");
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("url", "http://www.example.com");
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("structure", "Default Structure");
}

function drop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    var vm = [];
    vm.msg = {};
  vm.msg.appName = event.dataTransfer.getData("appName");
  vm.msg.code = event.dataTransfer.getData("code");
  vm.msg.url = event.dataTransfer.getData("url");
  vm.msg.structure = event.dataTransfer.getData("structure");
  console.log(vm.msg);
}

function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
#div1 {
    width: 350px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<label id="lbl" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Drop me</label>
```

Comment: I edited my original post, take a look please. I think I'm already doing it almost like your example.