# Blazor - ondrop event doesn't return file object

Tags: drag-and-drop, blazor, asp.net-blazor

I have bind **@ondrop** event into my **div** element, while drag and drop local image into div, **DragEventArgs** doesn't return **file object** details.

**Razor code**

```
<div @ondrop="@OnDrop"></div>

@code{
    internal void OnDrop(DragEventArgs args)
    {
        var files = args.DataTransfer.Files;
    }
}
```

output:

[image]

Anyone have solution for this case?

**Note**: *My main goal is to convert it as **FileStream** or **MemoryStream** then save it into specified location*

Comment: You can't without Javascript. If you look at Blazor source code no code handle DataTansfer. See here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5532

Comment: thanks for the reference link

Answer (score 1):

You should use preventDefault here:

```
<div @ondrop:preventDefault="@OnDrop"></div>
```

and maybe you still [have to handle Dragover as well](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8414154/60761), I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Still i am couldn't get the file object using suggested preventDefault and ondragover solution on blazor

Answer (score 1):

@ondrop event is useless here since it only reports the filename.
Blazor InputFile component triggers it's OnChange event when you drop a file on it's visible area.
The trick is to hide an InputFile component inside a drop area and spread it to fill the area completely.
The OnChange event handler receives a collection of IBrowseFile objects which can be read into MemoryStreams.
Further more, clicking on the drop area will open a file dialog the same way as if you had clicked on the InputFile.

```
<p>drop files on next area or click on it to select files:</p>

<div class="FileDrop">
    <InputFile multiple OnChange="FilesDropped"></InputFile>
</div>

@code {
    void FilesDropped(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(var file in e.GetMultipleFiles())
        {
            Stream stream = file.OpenReadStream(maxAllowedSize: 100000000);
            // TO DO: do whatever you need with the file
            stream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Use next Css to spread and hide the InputFile inside the drop area.
Note the use of ::deep pseudoelement to access the controls inside InputFile.

```
.FileDrop {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px dashed black;
}
.FileDrop ::deep input[type=file] {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the only solution that work with .net 8.